# Error; String indices must be integers, pretty sure the values ARE integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, indices

Assignment is to write a code that returns the second half of a string. Getting an error on this saying the indices must be integers, but I can't seem to figure out where the problem is.Help is appreciated

```
def last_half(sent):
    string_length = len(sent)
    if string_length / 2 == 0:
        s_half = int(string_length/2)
        print(sent[s_half,-1])
    elif string_length / 2 != 0:
        s_half = int(round(string_length/2))
        print(sent[s_half,-1])
```

Comment: I think `string_length / 2` should be `string_length % 2`. You're testing if it's even or odd, right?

Comment: And when the `elif` condition is the exact opposite of the `if` condition, you should use `else:`

Comment: **Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].**

Comment: As an aside, why have the function print the result instead of returning it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were using slicing wrongly. Have a look at https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/

```
def last_half(sent):
    string_length = len(sent)
    if string_length / 2 == 0:
        s_half = int(string_length/2)
        print(sent[s_half:])
    elif string_length / 2 != 0:
        s_half = int(round(string_length/2))
        print(sent[s_half:])
```

Comment: Man you are amazing, Thanks

Comment: Accept my answer if it helped (the green tick button)